# Getting last added item in Firebase using REST API

Tags: rest, firebase

how can I get the last added item in Firebase using rest api? I understand that firebase support filter as stated here 
`https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering` but I cannot find how to do it.

When I access the api endpoint `https://<firebaseproject>.firebaseio.com/messages.json?shallow=true` I got this data:

```
{
  "-KgclTDbCWnm5pxV7efg" : true,
  "-KgclglfW7bxGSeX6rlg" : true,
  "-Kgclo4-fQzWu095vELL" : true,
  "-Kgcm-R-GTJR670Co9kl" : true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using push IDs, the most recently added item will have the last key. You can get this item by:

```
https://<firebaseproject>.firebaseio.com/messages.json?orderBy="$key"&limitToLast=1
```